# OpenGL problem with transparency in textures

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I ran into a problem, well several problems, when rendering textures with transparency in them.

The texture that I am drawing is 64x64 px and it contains a white square (around 40x40 px) surrounded by transparency (r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0, so basically black-transparent):

[image]

There are some weird black/grey lines around the edges of the inner square when rendering the texture, as can be seen in the image:

[image]

I mean the grey lines at those borders don't always occur on all four sides of the square. They are mostly on the vertical sides of the square. I have set the background of the window to white, so I can see the problem much better. From what I gather, OpenGL is just basically blending between border of transparency and non-transparency in the texture. So between the color of the square (1, 1, 1, 1) and the color of transparency (0, 0, 0, 0), it blends it to (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f) or something.

Now you might tell me to change the transparency of the texture to being white-transparent (1, 1, 1, 0). I have done that too. That will hide the lines for this specific texture. But if I had a black square in the texture, and a white-transparent background and a black window background, then I would start seeing those lines again. And that's one of the "side" problems. When I export through Photoshop, I get a transparent background who's color is (1, 1, 1, 0). But when I export the texture through Paint.NET, I get a transparent background which is (0, 0, 0, 0). But I can deal with this problem later. First I need my first problem fixed which is with OpenGL. And btw, I use Java and LWJGL 3, which supports OpenGL.

Here is some code:

```
id = glGenTextures();
bind();
    
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    
unbind();
```

I use stbi.

Here's my fragment shader:

```
#version 440 core
out vec4 color;
in vec4 v_color;
in vec2 v_uv;
uniform sampler2D sampler;
void main() {
    color = texture(sampler, v_uv) * v_color;
}
```

`v_color` is just a color value that I can use to change the color of the texture. Rn it is just white.

My blending options are set to `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`.

Comment: I reworked your question a bit and removed a lot of unnecessary information. If you don't like it, feel free to roll back.

Comment: Regarding your problem: Are you trying to render the texture 1-1 to the screen or is there some scaling involved? In the first case, I'd disable linear interpolation and/or make sure that texel centers always fall on pixel centers (then there shouldn't be any interpolation happening).

Comment: Well, rn it is scaling 1-1. The texture size is 64x64 and the quad size is also 64x 64. And how did you remove info from my question? Can you edit my question? And what is a texel. I know there is something called half-pixel correction or something. I have tried that somewhat, but didn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: texel = one pixel in a texture. Yes, what I meant was half-pixel correction. And turn min/mag filter to GL_NEAREST to stop interpolation. About edit: Anyone can edit your question on SO. Below 2k, the edit will be reviewed by other community members, but above that editing is always possible.

Comment: Why `GL_CLAMP` instead of `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`?

Comment: It's a common problem, and the solution is to use premultiplied alpha. I can't find a good reference on StackOverflow itself (I'm sure it exists though), but [this is a good article](http://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/gpus-prefer-premultiplication/).

Comment: genpfault. Idk that's what TheCherno did in his OpenGL series. I tried clamping to edge and what not but that doesn't really solve the issue

Comment: Thomas, can you provide a way I can implement it in my code? I really don't wanna go thru the trouble of reading a whole freakin article. I will definitely do when I have time.

Comment: If someone links an article explaining the solution go read it man. With that said, try what BDL suggested. `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);`

Comment: i did try it Mudkip. I tried messing with those filtering options. It doesn't fix it. Even if it does, I run into very jagged textures when scaled down. I read that article. I did premultiplication of my pngs. It worked, but now I can't change the alpha value of my texture. For example, if i want my texture to "fade away" i can't do that. My blend func is glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) that's the one which works with premultiplied pngs. Edit: And also, I can't properly tint my textures if I want.